# union in common lisp, preserving order of elements in original lists

Tags: common-lisp

I'm working my way through Paul Graham's "ANSI Common Lisp" (1996).
Chapter 3, exercises, qu. 2 asks for a function as stated in title of this post. I'm only using what has been taught in the book up to this point (obviously there's `case` construct that could clean up the `if`'s but I'm not minding that at present).

As a first attempt I ended up writing interleave, which retains duplicates:

```lisp
(defun interleave (x y)
  (if (and (null x)      
           (null y))
      nil
      (if (null x)
          (cons (car y)
                (interleave (cdr y) x))
          ; where y is null, but also for any other case:
          (cons (car x)
                (interleave y (cdr x))))))
```

Following that, I had the idea to store a carry of elements which have been seen, and defer to a helper function, as below.
However, the below is obviously rather ugly and hard to understand.
I'm seeking some suggestions on directions I might take to achieve elegance.

Tips on **approach & style** might be just as useful at this point as providing the canonical solution. Should my number one impulse given code below be to extract another function? (or maybe I've gone in the wrong direction trying to store the carry in the first place?) Thank you fellow hackers!

```lisp
(defun new-union (x y)
  (new-union-helper x y '()))  ; <- idea, add a carry to store what's been seen.

(defun new-union-helper (x y seen)
  (if (and (null x)
           (null y))
      nil
      (if (null x)
          (if (not (member (car y) seen)) ; if first el of y hasn't yet been seen...
              ; cons it to the ultimate result & recur, while adding it to seen:
              (cons (car y) (new-union-helper (cdr y) x (cons (car y) seen)))
              ; if it has been seen, just continue, (skip the duplicate):
              (new-union-helper (cdr y) x seen))
          (if (not (member (car x) seen))
              (cons (car x) (new-union-helper y (cdr x) (cons (car x) seen)))
              (new-union-helper (cdr x) y seen)))))
```

Update: I've attempted to replace the nested `if`s with `cond`, having looked up `cond` in the index of the book. Sorry in advance, this is so ugly... but if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here that would be greatly appreciated. This code works same as above, but it prints a nil as the last member of the resulting list (on some inputs), not sure why yet.

```
; attempt to use cond instead:
(defun new-union-helper (x y seen)
  (cond ((and (null x) (null y))
         nil)
        ((and (null x) (not (member (car y) seen)))
         (cons (car y) (new-union-helper (cdr y) x (cons (car y) seen))))
        ((null x)
                       (new-union-helper (cdr y) x seen))
        ((not (member (car x) seen))
         (cons (car x) (new-union-helper y (cdr x) (cons (car x) seen))))
        (t
         (new-union-helper (cdr x) y seen))))
```

Update 2: I've tried to adopt better indenting. The below does what I want it to do from informal tests. Any further tips on what I'm still doing wrong? (I realise I should maybe abandon this and pursue another path, but since this is a learning exercise I wanted to fix as many potential bad habits as possible, early, before continuing on a new path).

How does this rate on the ugliness stakes? :)  Is it now readable to an experienced lisper?

```
; better (standard?) formatting
(defun new-union-helper (x y seen)
  (cond ((and (null x) 
              (null y))
         nil)
        ((and (null x) 
              (member (car y) seen)) ; replacing find with member stops duplicate nils
         (new-union-helper (cdr y) x seen))
        ((null x)
         (cons (car y) 
               (new-union-helper (cdr y) x 
                                 (cons (car y) seen))))
        ((member (car x) seen) 
         (new-union-helper (cdr x) y seen))
        (t
         (cons (car x) 
               (new-union-helper y (cdr x) 
                                 (cons (car x) seen))))))
```

Comment: I'd start by trying to specify the problem a little better, because Graham's question is pretty unclear.  What does "preserving the order of elements in the original lists" actually *mean* (especially for conflicting orders)?  What should `(new-union '(a b) '(b a))` return?  The example in the book seems to prefer the first list's order in case of conflicts.  What about `(new-union '(a b c) '(b a x c))`?  Does this need to return `(a b x c)` to preserve the x->c order in the second list?  Does performance matter?  Can the result share structure with the arguments?

Comment: Either your syntax is not good since `if` can only have 3 parts and not 5 or your formatting sucks and makes it impossible to read the code.
Keeping a list with seen elements is not optimal. It makes it O(n^2). Keeping the seen elements in a hash table is much better. I know this is for study but perhaps you should implement `remove-duplicates` (standard CL function, but you only need to support lists) and then it becomes `(remove-duplicates (append x y))`

Comment: @Sylwester - you're right, thanks. i've adjusted it -- is what i have now any less awful?  wondering what the next step to tidy it up is -- maybe replace those nested ifs somehow?

Comment: @SteveLosh - I had realised the problem specification was ambiguous, but since it's just an exercise and there are no answers provided anyway, i figured i could choose an exact spec during the development process. obviously not what you'd do in different context :)

Comment: I've added `not` to the conditionals & reversed the order of the sub-blocks under the `if`s, simply to make intention a bit clearer, plus added code comments...   further criticism would be very welcome :)

Comment: I tried introducing a let, `(let ((el (car y)))`... which is maybe a marginal improvement; also tried using a `cond` but that became more verbose/confusing.  Can anyone suggest which CL construct can best clean up the branching aspect of the above (all the ifs)?

Comment: don't use `FIND`. It does not do what you think it does. It's not a predicate. It finds an element. `(find nil '(nil)) -> nil` Here it found `nil` and returned it.

Comment: I've removed a rogue `and` which should not have been there in the third subexpression of `cond` (typo in converting from `if` to `cond`), and now no longer get the occasional `nil` at the end of the output list. i don't have any real testing set up yet obviously though. PG says in the book that lisp has universally accepted indentation conventions. Does that still apply to what I have above? (I don't believe I'm following it otherwise I'd use more than double the number of lines - what should I do next?) (maybe just abandon the cond version above... ?)

Comment: I've also now added 'update 2' which is the same code but my attempt to adopt standard indentation (pretty much what standard sublime text seems to want to give).

Comment: @RainerJoswig yes, it can't cope with `nil` as a list element: any duplicate `nil`s in input remain in the output. There be dragons. Maybe I'll leave grokking that aspect to the future (maybe first priority should be code structure & readability at this point?), & onward with PG's book...   :)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You would just not use FIND, which finds an object, but a MEMBERship predicate. Hmm, what could be the name of such a function?

Comment: I'm confused. In CL a predicate is generally something with a `p` at the end of the function name. PG introduces `member` in the context of sets (sec. 3.10), however, as he says, "when member returns true, instead of simply returning t, it returns the part of the list beginning with the object it was looking for", so `member` doesn't return only `t` or `nil` either, and is not therefore predicate(?) Are we talking style here or correctness?

Comment: Ah - I get it (sort of). Using `member` instead of `find` fixes the problem of it not removing duplicate `nil`s. :)

Comment: MEMBER will always return NIL when the thing is not an element. It also will always return a value which is true, when the thing is an element, This is unlike FIND, which has a different purpose and thus different behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun new-union (list1 list2 &aux (list3 (reverse list1)))
  (loop for e in list2 do (pushnew e list3))
  (reverse list3))

(defun new-union (list1 list2 &aux (list3 (reverse list1)))
  (dolist (e list2 (reverse list3))
    (pushnew e list3)))
```

Comment: what's the bit after the rest parameter? doesn't look like destructuring. is it serving a bit like a let?

Comment: I haven't entirely got to grips with this yet, to be able to confidently mark your answer correct, (confused re. adjoin vs pushnew as mentioned in the book which seem to do the same thing), but I pasted your functions above into my clisp repl & find that they don't actually do a set union - they don't remove duplicates... ?  ... but that said, I was testing using *lists of integers* - when I switch to lists of symbols '(a b c) etc., it appears to work as intended.

Comment: @mwal: default comparison predicate is EQL in Common Lisp. If you want to compare lists, you need something else. For example `(pushnew item place :test #'equal)`. See the documentation of PUSHNEW.

Answer (score 1):

Union takes two lists as arguments and will return a new list with the duplicates removed as you know. You want to retain the order of the original lists it appears. The specific question from the book if I recall is that if you have the lists:

```
(new-union '(a b c) '(b a d))
```

It should return:

```
(A B C D)
```

in order to maintain the proper order. So i'd imagine you need a function that takes two lists obviously, and something such as an accumulator so that you do not destructure the original lists. Union is a "non-destructuring" function. Since we are working with lists, you can use the dolist macro so that we can loop through both lists. That would lead us to the conclusion that the function below may work, as it will maintain the original structure of both lists, maintain the order of both lists, and remove duplicates:

```
(defun new-union(lst1 lst2)
   (let((accum nil))
     (dolist(x lst1)
       (push x accum))
     (dolist(y lst2)
       (if(not(find y accum))
      (push y accum)))
     (nreverse accum))
```

We can push each element from the first list to our accumulator, and then we can iterate through the second list and ONLY push it to the list if it is not an element that has already been pushed to the accumulator. This way, we avoid duplicates, maintain the structure of both of the original lists, and maintain the proper order if we return the our accumulator with the reverse function. Let's test it in the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (new-union '(a b c) '(b a d))
(A B C D)
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I've ended up hacking in a number of different directions on this (just now seeking to understand how `cond` can be an improvement over `if`, and in what cases; as illustrated in update to original post above). So, I'll take a look at your solution tomorrow with a fresh mind. Looking forward to that.Thank you Simeon! :)

Comment: Almost. `(new-union '(t nil) '(nil t)) -> (T NIL NIL)`

Comment: Also see the macro `pushnew`.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo When you say "non-destructuring", do you actually mean "non-destructive"? i know what destructuring is in clojure, haven't encountered it in CL yet. Also, obviously with clojure and fp destructive operations are not generally an option, but i understand common lisp is multi-paradigm..., needing to be aware of that(!)

Comment: Yes, it’s what you’d consider destructive (aka altering a list, and not simply returning a value for a list). You’ll come across what you mentioned in clojure in lisp, but moreso in terms of macro definitions. The book you’re referencing has a minor chapter on macros, but i’d Read “on lisp” by graham (‘93) when you’re done. What you mentioned in clojure occurs with macro definitions more so than anything else when you pass a parameter list. The “do” macro is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive implementation. It can be made faster with a few hacks. For example, a hash-table may be used to save elements that have been seen. In that case, find will be replaced with a hash-table lookup which is constant time.

```
(defun new-union (lst1 lst2)
  "return xs U ys preserving order in originals"
  (labels ((rec (xs ys acc)
             (let ((x (car xs))
                   (xx (cdr xs))
                   (y (car ys))
                   (yy (cdr ys)))
               (cond ((and (null xs) (null ys))
                      acc)
                     ((null xs)
                      (or (and (find y acc) (rec xx yy acc))
                          (rec xx yy (cons y acc))))
                     ((null ys)
                      (or (and (find x acc) (rec xx yy acc))
                          (rec xx yy (cons x acc))))
                     ((and (find x acc) (find y acc))
                      (rec xx yy acc))
                     ((and (find x acc) (not (find y acc)))
                      (rec xx yy (cons y acc)))
                     ((and (not (find x acc)) (find y acc))
                      (rec xx yy (cons x acc)))
                     (t (rec xx yy (cons y (cons x acc))))))))
    (nreverse (rec lst1 lst2 nil))))
```